# How to concatenate multiple csv file with one common column

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple csv files with different columns and one common EMP_ID column. I want to merge all the files and get one file with all the columns and header from different files. I tried the following code and I get the EMP_ID column multiple times.

file 1 :

| EMP_ID | EMP_name | EMP_Service |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 33 | a | 6 |
| 44 | b | 3 |
| 12 | c | 1 |
| 16 | d | 10 |
| 10 | e | 25 |

File 2:

| EMP_ID | EMP_age |
| --- | --- |
| 33 | 30 |
| 44 | 29 |
| 12 | 27 |
| 16 | 45 |
| 10 | 50 |

File 3:

| EMP_ID | EMP_dept |
| --- | --- |
| 33 | xyz |
| 44 | abc |
| 12 | lmn |
| 16 | abc |
| 10 | lmn |

required output: cat_vars.csv

| EMP_ID | EMP_name | EMP_age | EMP_Service | EMP_dept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 33 | a | 30 | 6 | xyz |
| 44 | b | 29 | 3 | abc |
| 12 | r | 27 | 1 | lmn |
| 16 | d | 45 | 10 | abc |
| 10 | t | 50 | 25 | lmn |

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(r'file_1.csv')
df2 =  pd.read_csv(r'file_2.csv')
df3 =  pd.read_csv(r'file_3.csv')

df = (pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1).to_csv('cat_vars.csv', index=False))
```

Comment: Specifically, there's a section in that answer: [How do I merge multiple DataFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101/65167327#65167327)

Comment: btw, `EMP_Code` isn't in any of your example inputs~

Comment: @BeRT2me I removed it that was by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your index as the column you want to join on~

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

dfs = [x.set_index('EMP_ID') for x in dfs]

df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).reset_index()

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   EMP_ID EMP_name  EMP_Service  EMP_age EMP_dept
0      33        a            6       30      xyz
1      44        b            3       29      abc
2      12        c            1       27      lmn
3      16        d           10       45      abc
4      10        e           25       50      lmn
```